# How to remove duplicates based on two columns removing the the largest of 3rd column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe that is like this:

```
df=
A  B  6  2
A  C  4  2
D  F  9  3
K  L  8  9
A  B  4  3
D  F  8  2
```

How can I say, if columns A and B have duplicates remove the ones that have the largest column C?

So for instance we can see lines 1 and 5 have the same columns A and B.

```
A  B  6  2 (Line 1)
A  B  4  3 (Line 5)
```

I want to remove line 1 as 6 is greater than 4.

So my output should be

```
A  C  4  2
K  L  8  9
A  B  4  3
D  F  8  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sorting the column in descending order on which you need to find max value using
[`pd.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Then drop_duplicates using [`pd.drop_duplicate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.sort_values(by=['C'],ascending=[True],inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'],inplace=True)
```

Comment: This didn't work until I changed ascending to be true. What is going on????

Comment: sorry I thought you want to delete lowest value

Comment: @chrisrever111 i have updated the answer you need to do ascending =True